# Ruby overriding array access operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets-api

I have to set worksheet cell value on command `ws['First Col'][1]= 255` for example.

I have tried this:

```
def [](*args)
  return Column.new(self.find_column_index(args[0])) if args[0].is_a?(String) and args[1] != nil
  return cell_name_to_row_col(args[0]) if args[0].is_a?(String) and args[1] == nil
  (row, col) = parse_cell_args(args)
  cells[[row, col]] || ''
end

class Column

  def initialize(column)
    @column = column
  end

  def []=(row, value)
    self[row+1,@column] = value
    self.save
  end
end
```

It's not working.

In `def [](*args)`, I have few `if`s because for input ws['First Col'], it has to return all rows from first column, and for `ws[1,2]` it has to return second cell in first row for example.

I have also tried to tweak it a bit but I could not make it work.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its current form. The code you posted looks like it was taken out of context and additionally "simplified" so it makes little to no sense now. For example, your `Column` class doesn't implement either `[]` or `save` methods but you still call them, the top-level `[]` method refers to `cells` that is not defined before etc... Could you clarify it a bit, please?

Comment: Column class was how I have made it to work earlier but I can't make it work with other implementations. I am just learning ruby so thats why it may look simplified. Worksheet is from google docs. I am up for redesign as clearly I have no idea how to solve this @KonstantinStrukov

Comment: Right now your `[]` method is trying to do too much at once e.g. sometimes it returns a `Column`, sometimes it returns a "cell". I think you would be better off with `rows` and `columns` methods. Take a look at how `caxlsx` implements this. It's pretty straight forward. [`Axlsx::Worksheet#rows`](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/worksheet.rb#L146) and [`Axlsx::Worksheet#cols`](https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/workbook/worksheet/worksheet.rb#L156)